# Minimum rights to access the whole Users directory on another computer

Tags: permissions, active-directory

What is the minimum rights required to access the Users directory on another computer via an admin share?

I have a batch file that writes some information to a few other computers using a path of \\%COMPUTERNAME%\c$\Users\%USERNAME%\AppData\Roaming.  The batch files run under an unprivileged user (part of Domain Users only).  How do I set appropriate rights so that service account can access the AppData\Roaming folder for every user on another computer?

I'd like to give rights lower than Local Admin, which I know will work.

Things I've attempted:

1. As Domain Admin, attempted to give Modify rights to the C:\Users\ directory on the local computer.  Error: Access Denied.
2. Set the service account as Local Admin on the other computer.  This works, but is against IT policy where I work.  I'd like to accomplish this with rights lower than Local Admin.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Viewing or accessing another user's profile directory requires ownership of the folder.

Comment: Are you sure this information has to go into the user's Profile directory.  There are better places for shared data.

Comment: Unfortunately, yes.  We have some engineering/mapping software that stores location data in AppData\Roaming under each individual's user profile.  The software is used for real-time incident mapping, so the batch file copies incident locations from a central source to each user directory on each computer that needs it... It's a mess, but it worked fine when the service account was a Domain Admin.

Comment: Have you tried setting the ownership to this other user?  Its working as an Administrator because those groups already have ownership.

Comment: I set ownership for the service account on C:\Users, and marked to push permissions to all subfolders and objects.  Didn't work.  I still get access denied when navigating to \\computer\c$\Users\ or \\computer\c$\Users\username\AppData\Roaming.

Comment: When you hit Properties on those folders.  What users are listed?

Comment: The service account is listed with Full Control, and also shown as Owner.  I think what I'm trying to do isn't really possible... I'll expound more in answering my own question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Administrative_share),

> Administrative shares cannot be accessed by users without
>   administrative privileges.

In order to access `\\computername\c$` at all, the service account must be a member of the Local Administrators group.  The same goes for `\\computername\admin$`.

I tried to get around that by creating a new share called `Users$` mapped to `C:\Users` on the local computer.  I gave the service account `Change` rights on the share, and attempted to give `Modify` rights on the folder itself.  I separately attempted to assign ownership of `C:\Users` to the service account.

This did not work as I had hoped.  In setting rights, I got an `Access is Denied` error on several subfolders (for instance, `C:\Users\username\AppData\Local` for each user).  As I only needed access to `C:\Users\username\AppData\Roaming` for each user, this came **close** to a workable solution, and was accessible from the other computer using `\\computername\Users$\username\AppData\Roaming`.  **The down side:** Any new user logging in on that machine did not inherit the rights automatically.  I had to reassign rights for each new user.

Ultimately, the IT department granted a policy exception giving local Admin to the service account on each computer affected, giving me unfettered access to `\\computername\c$\Users\`.

Thank you especially to @Ramhound for assistance in this matter.